# Class Landlord does not exist - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I installed laravel's landlord package and after setting up the provider, facade and also publishing the config, i get **Class Landlord does not exist** on page load.

Comment: Tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Yes. Didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code please

Comment: How are we suppose to know what is going on with your namespaces when you ask a question with no info whatsoever ?

Comment: Also, presumably it's the `HipsterJazzbo\Landlord` package, what exactly are you looking to achieve that is different from a standard belongsTo relationship? That's pretty much all this does.

Comment: There is nothing to show(code). It gives the error on page load. I only did the installation. I'm not sure which code you're talking about.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi I never said anything about namespaces. You can try and see my comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you've added an alias:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Landlord'   => HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\Facades\Landlord::class,
],
```

Then just add this line to the top of the class, where you're trying to use the package:

```
use Landlord;
```

Or just use full name of facade:

```
\Landlord::addTenant('tenant_id', 1);
```

Comment: I did add an alias. But i can't even use the package because i keep getting the error when i reload the page.

Comment: @PeterTaiwo did you add `use Landlord;`? If so, try to run `composer du` command. If this will not help, it means the package is not installed (look in the `vendor` directory) or loaded (you didn't add service provider in `config/app.php`).

Comment: i installed it using the example given on github. I have checked the vendor directory and it is there and also confirmed that i added it to config/app.php. Thanks